# Average value of a given probability distribution of Quantum Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, probability

I've read a question:

in a measurement of a quantity, the probability distribution is:
$$P(k)=e^{-\mu} \left(\frac {\mu^k}{k!}\right)$$

and when we calculate the average value of $k$, $k^2$:

$$〈k〉=\sum_{k=0}^\infty kP(k) = e^{-\mu} \sum_{k=0}^\infty k\frac {\mu^k}{k!} = e^{-\mu} \left(\mu\frac{\partial}{\partial \mu}\right) \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac {\mu^k}{k!} = e^{-\mu} \left(\mu\frac{\partial}{\partial \mu}\right) e^{\mu} = \mu$$

$$〈k^2〉=\sum_{k=0}^\infty k^2P(k) = e^{-\mu} \sum_{k=0}^\infty [k(k-1)+k]\frac {\mu^k}{k!} = e^{-\mu} \sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\mu^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\mu^2}+\mu\frac{\partial}{\partial\mu}\right)\frac {\mu^k}{k!}= e^{-\mu}\left(\mu^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\mu^2}+\mu\frac{\partial}{\partial\mu}\right)e^\mu=\mu^2+\mu$$

what I don't understand in these equations are:

1. why $k=\mu\frac{\partial}{\partial\mu}$ in the third equation of $〈k〉$?
2. why we need to rewrite $k^2=k(k-1)+k$ in the second equation of $〈k^2〉$?
3. why $k(k-1)+k$ = $\mu^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\mu^2}+\mu\frac{\partial}{\partial\mu}$ rather $\mu^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\mu^2}-\mu\frac{\partial}{\partial\mu}+\mu\frac{\partial}{\partial\mu} = \mu^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\mu^2}$ in the third equation of $〈k^2〉$?

Answer (score 3):

It's just a trick, which I think is called the *Feynman trick*, and it's used to solve integrals and sums for which the argument is well-behaved. You just have to notice that $$k\frac{\mu^k}{k!} = \frac{\mu}{k!}\frac{d\mu^{k}}{d\mu}$$ In fact the derivative brings down a $k$ but then the exponent will be $\mu^{k-1}$, so you multiply by $\mu$ to get back with what you started. Same goes for the second derivative, which will explain why one writes $k^2 = k(k-1)+k$ since $$k(k-1)\frac{\mu^k}{k!} = \frac{\mu^2}{k!}\frac{d\mu^{k}}{d\mu}$$ In fact the first derivative brings down a $k$ and the power of $\mu$ becomes $k-1$, then the second derivative brings down a $k-1$, so you have a total of $k(k-1)$ in front, and the exponent of $\mu$ becomes $k-2$ so to get back what you started with you multiply by $\mu^2$.

All of this just so you go back to a known power series, which in this case is $$\sum_k \frac{\mu^k}{k!} = e^{\mu}$$

There are some rules on the "smoothness" of the argument which ensure that you can put the derivatives outside the sum (or the integral), for them I'm sure you'll find a lot all over the web.

Comment: I think it's just a question of convergence, if the series or integral converges, then you can differentiate or integrate it term by term. Of course, I'm not sure if there are any esoteric counter-examples.... there might be.

Comment: Yes, I didn't want to go into the details but, if my mind serves me correctly, you need to have convergence of the initial sum and uniform convergence of the sum of the derivatives. The latter is pretty easy since the sum uniformly converges to $e^\mu$, but there remains to prove the convergence of the initial series.

Comment: One might add that the trick with the derivative is not really needed here: one can use the definition of the factorial ($k!=k (k-1)! = k(k-1)(k-2)!$) and simple index change.

Comment: @Vadim And then one need not worry about convergence and such, neat!